# Toast crash during main thread execution

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-toast

I've got a method test() that runs every 3 seconds in main thread using the following Runnable and Handler decleration:

```
private Runnable _checker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        test();
    } finally {
        if (!_stopTest) {
            _testHandler.postDelayed(_checker, 3000);
        }
    }
    }
};
```

This toast message runs on main thread during test() method:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Recalculating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

ends up with exception:

> ```
> 04-02 09:56:44.229 31232-31232/com.app E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                      at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:105)
>                                                                      at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:262)
>                                                                      at com.BaseSupportFragment.test(BaseSupportFragment.java:916)
> ```

The exception occurs during onBackPressed, which I override to remove the fragment container (which contains the fragment that should show the toast message that fails).

Does anybody know what happens here?

Comment: I'd say activity was detached from fragment before Toast.makeText is called so Context is missing and it causes NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The exception occurs during onBackPressed.

Next time `getActivity()` is called it returns `null`, because your fragment currently is not attached to any activity. Thus crash happens.

In `onBackPress()` you have to cancel scheduled runnables:

```
_testHandler.removeCallbacks(_checker);
```

Comment: Also: adding condition if (!_stopTest) before the call test() is required.